# Type of sankey diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I  searched and identified a type of sankey diagram that could show the software lifecycle as swimlanes and the tool chain used. I code basic tex but need some help. Are there libraries that can support this diagram ? Can I see some examples ?

I don't plan to use all the features of Sankey but only the layout shown here. I use texmaker and Mactex. I have some idea about how this code could work. The shapes and swimlanes are missing though. I tried this code posted in the other thread and it works but haven't made much headway after this.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{sankeydebug}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground,sankeydebug}

\newif\ifsankeydebug

\newenvironment{sankeydiagram}[1][]{

  \def\sankeyflow##1##2{% sn, en
    \path[sankey fill]
    let
    \p1=(##1.north east),\p2=(##1.south east),
    \n1={atan2(\y1-\y2,\x1-\x2)-90},
    \p3=(##2.north west),\p4=(##2.south west),
    \n2={atan2(\y3-\y4,\x3-\x4)+90}
    in
    (\p1) to[out=\n1,in=\n2] (\p3) --
    (\p4) to[in=\n1,out=\n2] (\p2) -- cycle;
    \draw[sankey draw]
    let
    \p1=(##1.north east),\p2=(##1.south east),
    \n1={atan2(\y1-\y2,\x1-\x2)-90},
    \p3=(##2.north west),\p4=(##2.south west),
    \n2={atan2(\y3-\y4,\x3-\x4)+90}
    in
    (\p1) to[out=\n1,in=\n2] (\p3)
    (\p4) to[in=\n1,out=\n2] (\p2);
  }


  \tikzset{
    sankey tot length/.store in=\sankeytotallen,
    sankey tot quantity/.store in=\sankeytotalqty,
    sankey min radius/.store in=\sankeyminradius,
    sankey arrow length/.store in=\sankeyarrowlen,
    sankey debug/.is if=sankeydebug,
    sankey debug=false,
    sankey flow/.style={
      to path={
        \pgfextra{
          \pgfinterruptpath
          \edef\sankeystart{\tikztostart}
          \edef\sankeytarget{\tikztotarget}
          \sankeyflow{\sankeystart}{\sankeytarget}
          \endpgfinterruptpath
        }
      },
    },
    sankey node/.style={
      inner sep=0,minimum height={sankeyqtytolen(##1)},
      minimum width=0,draw=none,line width=0pt,
    },
    % sankey angle
    sankey angle/.store in=\sankeyangle,
    % sankey default styles
    sankey fill/.style={line width=0pt,fill,white},
    sankey draw/.style={draw=black,line width=.4pt},
  }

  \newcommand\sankeynode[4]{%prop,orientation,name,pos
    \node[sankey node=##1,rotate=##2] (##3) at (##4) {};
    \ifsankeydebug
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{sankeydebug}
      \draw[red,|-|] (##3.north west) -- (##3.south west);
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\len}{sankeyqtytolen(##1)/3}
      \draw[red] (##3.west)
      -- ($(##3.west)!\len pt!90:(##3.south west)$)
      node[font=\tiny,text=black] {##3};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \fi
  }

  \newcommand\sankeynodestart[4]{%prop,orientation,name,pos
    \sankeynode{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(##3)},rotate=##2]
      \path[sankey fill]
      (##3.north west) -- ++(-\sankeyarrowlen,0)
      -- ([xshift=-\sankeyarrowlen/6]##3.west)
      -- ([xshift=-\sankeyarrowlen]##3.south west)
      -- (##3.south west) -- cycle;
      \path[sankey draw]
      (##3.north west) -- ++(-\sankeyarrowlen,0)
      -- ([xshift=-\sankeyarrowlen/6]##3.west)
      -- ([xshift=-\sankeyarrowlen]##3.south west)
      -- (##3.south west);
    \end{scope}
  }

  \newcommand\sankeynodeend[4]{%prop,orientation,name,pos
    \sankeynode{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}
    \begin{scope}[shift={(##3)},rotate=##2]
      \path[sankey fill]
      (##3.north east)
      -- ([xshift=\sankeyarrowlen]##3.east)
      -- (##3.south west) -- cycle;
      \path[sankey draw]
      (##3.north east)
      -- ([xshift=\sankeyarrowlen]##3.east)
      -- (##3.south west);
    \end{scope}
  }

  \newcommand\sankeyadvance[3][]{%newname,name,distance
    \edef\name{##2}
    \ifstrempty{##1}{
      \def\newname{##2}
      \edef\name{##2-old}
      \path [late options={name=##2,alias=\name}];
    }{
      \def\newname{##1}
    }
    \path
    let
    % sankey node angle
    \p1=(##2.north east),
    \p2=(##2.south east),
    \n1={atan2(\y1-\y2,\x1-\x2)-90},
    % sankey prop
    \p3=($(\p1)-(\p2)$),
    \n2={sankeylentoqty(veclen(\x3,\y3))},
    % next position
    \p4=($(##2.east)!##3!-90:(##2.north east)$)
    in
    \pgfextra{
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\prop}{\n2}
      \pgfinterruptpath
      \sankeynode{\prop}{\n1}{\newname}{\p4}
      \path (\name) to[sankey flow] (\newname);
      \endpgfinterruptpath
    };
  }

  \newcommand\sankeyturn[3][]{%newname,name,angle
    \edef\name{##2}
    \ifstrempty{##1}{
      \def\newname{##2}
      \edef\name{##2-old}
      \path [late options={name=##2,alias=\name}];
    }{
      \def\newname{##1}
    }
    \ifnumgreater{##3}{0}{
      \typeout{turn acw: ##3}
      \path
      let
      % sankey node angle
      \p1=(##2.north east),
      \p2=(##2.south east),
      \p3=($(\p1)!-\sankeyminradius!(\p2)$),
      \n1={atan2(\y1-\y2,\x1-\x2)-90},
      % sankey prop
      \p4=($(\p1)-(\p2)$),
      \n2={sankeylentoqty(veclen(\x4,\y4))},
      \p5=(##2.east),
      \p6=($(\p3)!1!##3:(\p5)$)
      in
      \pgfextra{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\prop}{\n2}
        \pgfinterruptpath
        % \fill[red] (\p3) circle (2pt);
        % \fill[blue](\p6) circle (2pt);
        \sankeynode{\prop}{\n1+##3}{\newname}{\p6}
        \path (\name) to[sankey flow] (\newname);
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      };
    }{
      \typeout{turn acw: ##3}
      \path
      let
      % sankey node angle
      \p1=(##2.south east),
      \p2=(##2.north east),
      \p3=($(\p1)!-\sankeyminradius!(\p2)$),
      \n1={atan2(\y1-\y2,\x1-\x2)+90},
      % sankey prop
      \p4=($(\p1)-(\p2)$),
      \n2={sankeylentoqty(veclen(\x4,\y4))},
      \p5=(##2.east),
      \p6=($(\p3)!1!##3:(\p5)$)
      in
      \pgfextra{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\prop}{\n2}
        \pgfinterruptpath
        % \fill[red] (\p3) circle (2pt);
        % \fill[blue](\p6) circle (2pt);
        \sankeynode{\prop}{\n1+##3}{\newname}{\p6}
        \path (\name) to[sankey flow] (\newname);
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      };
    }
  }

  \newcommand\sankeyfork[2]{%name,list of forks
    \def\name{##1}
    \def\listofforks{##2}
    \xdef\sankeytot{0}
    \path 
    let
    % sankey node angle
    \p1=(\name.north east),
    \p2=(\name.south east),
    \n1={atan2(\y1-\y2,\x1-\x2)-90},
    % sankey prop
    \p4=($(\p1)-(\p2)$),
    \n2={sankeylentoqty(veclen(\x4,\y4))}
    in
    \pgfextra{
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\iprop}{\n2}
    }
    \foreach \prop/\name[count=\c] in \listofforks {
      let
      \p{start \name}=($(\p1)!\sankeytot/\iprop!(\p2)$),
      \n{nexttot}={\sankeytot+\prop},
      \p{end \name}=($(\p1)!\n{nexttot}/\iprop!(\p2)$),
      \p{mid \name}=($(\p{start \name})!.5!(\p{end \name})$)
      in
      \pgfextra{
        \xdef\sankeytot{\n{nexttot}}
        \pgfinterruptpath
        \sankeynode{\prop}{\n1}{\name}{\p{mid \name}}
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      }
    }
    \pgfextra{
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\diff}{abs(\iprop-\sankeytot)}
      \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\finish}{\diff<0.01?1:0}
      \ifnumequal{\finish}{1}{}{
        \message{*** Warning: bad sankey fork (maybe)...}
        \message{\iprop-\sankeytot}
      }
    };
  }

  \tikzset{
    % default values,
    declare function={
      sankeyqtytolen(\qty)=\qty/\sankeytotalqty*\sankeytotallen;
      sankeylentoqty(\len)=\len/\sankeytotallen*\sankeytotalqty;
    },
    sankey tot length=100pt,
    sankey tot quantity=100,
    sankey min radius=30pt,%
    sankey arrow length=10pt,%
    % user values
    #1}
}{
}



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]

\begin{sankeydiagram}[
sankey tot length=5pt,%
sankey tot quantity=6,%
sankey min radius=15pt,%
sankey fill/.style={
  draw,line width=0pt,
  fill,
  green!50,
},
sankey draw/.style={
  draw=white,
  line width=1pt,
  line cap=round,
  line join=round,
},
]
\sankeynodestart{6}{-0}{p0}{0,10};
\sankeyadvance{p0}{70pt}
\sankeyfork{p0}{3/p1,3/p2}

\sankeyadvance{p2}{60pt}


 {
  \tikzset{
    sankey fill/.append style={
      line width=0pt,
      blue!50,
    }
  }
\sankeyturn{p1}{90}
}

\end{sankeydiagram}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The layout shown there doesn't have swimlanes.

Comment: I don't know what swimlanes are, do you mean the colored boxes in the background? If those are the problem, either edit your question focusing on that, so it can be reopened, or make a new question. If you can do the Sankey-part of the diagram, then add that code to your question as well.